# How to debug failure in LSQ Subproblem

Tags: openmdao

I'm solving a dymos problem with 'SLSQP' and the SCIPY Optimizer driver and my problem fails due to 'more than 3^n iterations in LSQ subproblem'. I've been trying to understand what exactly this error means to figure out where in my model I should start debugging, but I have not found any useful resources on the topic. You all provided useful feedback on how to debug other optimizer errors, so I figured that maybe you all had some advice for this error as well.

Note that my variable scaling is pretty good. Also, if I turn off the optimization variables `opt=False` and just let the optimizer converge the trajectories, the optimization completes. Then, if I enable the optimization variables `opt=True` and warm start the problem, the optimization converges as well. Although this works, I have to solve many different problems and finding a warm start solution to each problem is unrealistic. I also find it strange that the LSQ subproblem is so dependent on the initial guess.

Answer (score 0):

without more details, its hard to be very specific. However, its not terribly uncommon for optimizations in general and optimal-control optimizations based on psuedo-spectral methods in particular to be highly sensitive to initial values. The following is not proposed as a solution, nor even the general recommended best practice for all dymos cases. But for problems where you find you need a better initial guess, this is a good place to start:

```
import openmdao.api as om
import dymos as dm
from dymos.examples.plotting import plot_results
from dymos.examples.brachistochrone import BrachistochroneODE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#
# Initialize the Problem and the optimization driver
#
p = om.Problem(model=om.Group())
p.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
# p.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9
p.driver.declare_coloring()

#
# Create a trajectory and add a phase to it
#
traj = p.model.add_subsystem('traj', dm.Trajectory())

phase = traj.add_phase('phase0',
                       dm.Phase(ode_class=BrachistochroneODE,
                                transcription=dm.GaussLobatto(num_segments=10)))

#
# Set the variables
#
phase.set_time_options(fix_initial=True, duration_bounds=(.5, 10))

phase.add_state('x', fix_initial=True, fix_final=True)

phase.add_state('y', fix_initial=True, fix_final=True)

phase.add_state('v', fix_initial=True, fix_final=False)

phase.add_control('theta', continuity=True, rate_continuity=True,
                  units='deg', lower=0.01, upper=179.9)

phase.add_parameter('g', units='m/s**2', val=9.80665)

#
# Minimize time at the end of the phase
#
phase.add_objective('time', loc='final', scaler=10)

p.model.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver()

#
# Setup the Problem
#
p.setup()

# intial guesses for times and controls are important before running a sim
p['traj.phase0.t_initial'] = 0.0
p['traj.phase0.t_duration'] = 2.0
p.set_val('traj.phase0.controls:theta', phase.interp('theta', ys=[5, 100.5]))


# need this to set initial conditions for x,y,v so simulate starts from the right condition
p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:x', phase.interp('x', ys=[0, 10]))
p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:y', phase.interp('y', ys=[10, 5]))
p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:v', phase.interp('v', ys=[0, 9.9]))

# Run a simulation to get physically valid initial guesses
p.run_model()
exp_out = traj.simulate()

# extract the initial values out of the sim result
x_sim = exp_out.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.states:x')
y_sim = exp_out.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.states:y')
v_sim = exp_out.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.states:v')
t_sim = exp_out.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.time')

# need to manually reset the last value to the correct BCs for states where fix_final=True
# but the initial values will be correct because we set them above before sim
x_sim[-1] = 10
y_sim[-1] = 5



# set initial guesses based on initial sim into the model
# (Dymos will re-interpolate them onto the collocation grid)
# comment/uncomment these three lines to see the effect of the initial guess
p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:x', phase.interp('x', xs=t_sim, ys=x_sim))
p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:y', phase.interp('y', xs=t_sim, ys=y_sim))
p.set_val('traj.phase0.states:v', phase.interp('v', xs=t_sim, ys=v_sim))

#
# Solve for the optimal trajectory
#
dm.run_problem(p)

# Check the results
print(p.get_val('traj.phase0.timeseries.time')[-1])
```

When running without initial guesses i get:

```
Full total jacobian was computed 3 times, taking 0.019553 seconds.
Total jacobian shape: (40, 50)


Jacobian shape: (40, 50)  (19.95% nonzero)
FWD solves: 13   REV solves: 0
Total colors vs. total size: 13 vs 50  (74.0% improvement)

Sparsity computed using tolerance: 1e-25
Time to compute sparsity: 0.019553 sec.
Time to compute coloring: 0.028856 sec.
Memory to compute coloring: 0.000000 MB.
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: [18.0161673]
            Iterations: 24
            Function evaluations: 24
            Gradient evaluations: 24
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
[1.80161673]
```

When running with initial guesses I get:

```
Full total jacobian was computed 3 times, taking 0.020724 seconds.
Total jacobian shape: (40, 50)


Jacobian shape: (40, 50)  (19.95% nonzero)
FWD solves: 13   REV solves: 0
Total colors vs. total size: 13 vs 50  (74.0% improvement)

Sparsity computed using tolerance: 1e-25
Time to compute sparsity: 0.020724 sec.
Time to compute coloring: 0.029557 sec.
Memory to compute coloring: 0.000000 MB.
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: [18.01657396]
            Iterations: 11
            Function evaluations: 11
            Gradient evaluations: 11
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
[1.8016574]
```

So you can see that the initial guesses here helped converge things faster. Again I want to stress that this is not always the case. If I change the initial guess for final time (which is solved for as part of the optimization --- since the objective is to minimize travel time!) from 2 to 10, then the initial simulation is a much worse approximation of the final solution.

p['traj.phase0.t_duration'] = 10.0

Then I get this for the standard intial guess:

```
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: [18.01612053]
            Iterations: 39
            Function evaluations: 39
            Gradient evaluations: 39
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
[1.80161205]
```

And this for the simulated initial guess:

```
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: [18.01677452]
            Iterations: 43
            Function evaluations: 44
            Gradient evaluations: 43
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------
[1.80167745]
```

So the simulated guess took a few more iterations this time (though it still found the correct answer). You can intutively see why this is the case here, since I changed my initial estimate of the duration from 2 seconds (close to the optimal 1.801) to 10 seconds (far from the optimum) and hence the initial simulation was a much poorer estimate of the optimal solution.
So more generally, your ability to provide reasonable starting values for the non-state values (i.e. time, controls) will affect how good your initial guess from simulation is.

Even with "bad" simulation initial guesses you may still get improved stability on your optimization though.

One more note: although I manually input the guesses here for instructional purposes, dymos does have a helper function that can reload the guesses from a case database. See the `restart` argument to the [`run_problem` method](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/dymos/blob/master/dymos/run_problem.py).

Comment: This has been helpful. Looking back, I poorly explained my issue. Although I agree that warm starting is particularly helpful, my issue is that (1) getting a warm started solution is quite difficult (but maybe unavoidable) and (2) what is the LSQ subproblem and why is it taking so many iterations. I've debugged to figure out that a better initial guess helps with the LSQ subproblem error, but is there a better way to address this issue given that an initial guess is hard to get. Have people been able to identify the underlying cause of this error? I haven't found anything, but maybe you have?